# Catch 22 re Android Market Developer Agreement

Tags: android, google-play

This is not a programming question per se but a question that may be relevant to all *future* Android developers.

I am in the market for an Android developer phone. I can buy it used on eBay, or I can buy it new on the Android Market.

All nice and dandy but in order what the Android market has to offer, I have to first [register](http://market.android.com/publish/signup), which requires signing the [Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html).

Well, I know that many developers signed that agreement and stayed alive, but before signing anything I prefer to read what I am about to sign. Unfortunately, certain information that is needed to be understood in order to sign the agreement can be accessed only after you sign the agreement...

For example, how do I know which are the "authorized payment processors" mentioned in [clause 1.2](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html)?

Also, it sounds strange to me that in order to just see what developer phones are available (and their specs) I first have to register and pay the $25 registration fee. It will take at least 6 months before I will be ready to place anything on the Android market, so why should I register now?

Any idea whether to find these 2 pieces of information without having to register so early in the process?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: purchase an Android phone from a regular phone carrier such as Verizon, and don't get a service plan

Comment: Ian, thanks for link to Programmers Exchange. I wasn't aware of its existence.

Comment: @binnyb I prefer a GSM version over a CDMA one. Do you know which carrier offers one? Does it come with warranty?

Comment: @Android Eve: T-Mobile and AT&T both have Android phones, to my knowledge. Don't know about the warranty specifics.

Comment: Download Motodev and you can test on the emulator which emulates all versions from 1.5 to 2.2.  By the time you are ready to test on a real phone they will be cheaper on ebay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things, first the "Authorized Payment Processors" are defined just above that as:

> Payment Processor(s): Any party authorized by Google to provide payment processing services that enable Developers with optional Payment Accounts to charge Device users for Products distributed via the Market.Blockquote

The only one currently is Google Checkout, but I have heard that they are working with PayPal to get them involved as well.

Secondly, you have to log in to buy the phones because they are only available to Android Devs.  The ones on the list are the "Android Dev Phone 2" (which is basically a MyTouch 3G) for $399.00 and the Nexus One for $529.00.  You can look those up and check the specs on them.  They are both unlocked and the Nexus One has an unlocked bootloader.

Comment: +1 for listing the only payment processor currently authorized. I would have given you +5 for actually posting the exact the information I was looking for but stackoverflow only allows +1. So, I am going to mark your question as the accepted one. :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to register now. Just when you are ready to release your app to the Market.

Also, for development you can get any Android phone out there. Preferably many phones with different physical characteristics and various sw versions.

Btw, the $25 fee is a good thing, because Google records your credit card no, so malicious devs keep themselves away.

Comment: Peter, thanks for your answer. Can you provide a link to the developer phones offered by Google (aka Android Market) so that I can check them out without registering?

Comment: As I mentioned - there is nothing special about the Google Dev phones. You can develop Android apps on any Android phone. The only difference is that they are SIM-unlocked.

Comment: And you can get root or install your own firmware without having to find and exploit a security flaw in the original install - which is not necessary for developing sdk apps, but is necessary to fully leverage the potential of the device as a pocket linux box.